# why $(M_1^{\perp})^{\perp} \subset [T^*(H_2) ]^{\perp} ?$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have some confusion in subset sign  given below , my confusion marked in red circle as given below
[image]

It is given that  $T^*(H_2) \subset M_1^{ \perp}$ then  why  $(M_1^{\perp})^{\perp} \subset [T^*(H_2) ]^{\perp} ?$

I think  its should be  $[T^*(H_2) ]^{\perp}  \subset (M_1^{\perp})^{\perp}$

Comment: It is a fact from linear algebra that if $U$ is a subspace of $V$, then $V^{\perp}\subset U^{\perp}$.

Comment: If $\subset$ means "proper subset", then the claim is true for finite dimensional spaces but for infinite dimensional spaces it is generally not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $H$is an inner product space with inner product $( \cdot, \cdot)$ and isf $A \subset B \subset H,$ then we have

$$B^{\perp} \subset A^{\perp}.$$

Proof: let $x \in B^{\perp}$, then $(x,b)=0$ for all $b \in B.$ Since $A \subset B $, we get $(x,a)=0$ for all $a \in A.$ This gives $x \in A^{\perp}$.

Comment: What if $A$ and $B$ are dense subspaces?

Comment: @trancelocation then $B^\perp = A^\perp =\{0\}$. In this answer $\subset$ is probably a synonym for $\subseteq$, which is often done.

Comment: Yes, I used $ \subset$ as a synonym for $ \subseteq.$

Comment: @s.harp : This is exactly what my question is aiming at. To me $\subset$ is not an "often synonym" for $\subseteq$ and it should be clearly indicated what is meant by the symbol.